# How to add list of Strings to entity - Spring, Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have Spring Boot project with DB. I've already get table, let's call it "People". I need to add a second table "People_Strings" with two columns: `People_id` and `String`. I need to include many strings for every row from People.

How can I map it in my People entity in project?

Edit: I need to do this without creating separete class for `String` or for `People_Strings`

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us your code?

Comment: If you want to do this without separate classes you can store a list! And please ask your questions clearly at first

Answer (score 4):

If you only need that, you can add the following property to the `People` entity class:

```
@ElementCollection
public List<String> strings;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `@OneToMany` relation between people and strings. Something like the following will work for you.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "People")
public class People{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "peopleId")
  private List<PeopleStrings> PeopleStrings;

@Entity
@Table(name = "People_Strings")
public class PeopleStrings{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long peopleId;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="peopleId")
  private String string;
```

Comment: This is why I hate hibernate, that `FetchType.EAGER` is bound to cause a query to perform really badly in the future

Comment: Option 1: Ditch hibernate... avoid that nonsense all together!! (hibernate makes intelligent people write stupid queries) Option 2: Never eager fetch by default. If you want eager, you should explicitly say so when querying.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a `@OneToMany` relationship on the `Person` object (please don't use plurals, eg People). And possibly a `@ManyToOne` relationship on the `PersonString` object (again no plurals)

- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html
- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html

Answer (score -1):

This is kinda basic question and I suggest you to read Hibernate "Get Started" first. (one-to-many / many-to-one relations especially)

Comment: yup, it is basic question, when it comes to include list of Objects from other entity. I don't want to create separate class for Strings. So I'm asking if there's other way.

Comment: Then you should consider using a combination of `@ElementCollection`, `@MapKeyColumn` and `@CollectionTable`